# Why do jQuery's .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() stop working when a transition is applied in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I apply a transition on an element with CSS, jQuery's `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`  stop working.

I have a Solution for this but, **why does this happen**?

Why do `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()`  work like `.hide()` ?

Where have the effects gone while there is a css transition being applied?

When I have to apply any jQuery animation, I always remove the transition and then apply jQuery animation and then add the transition back!

Is there any other trick to do this? Or is this the only way?

```
  cloned.css('transition', 'none');
  cloned.fadeOut();

  setTimeout(function(){

    cloned.css('transition', 'all 500ms  cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 1.5)');

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeOut and fadeIn will work with transitions, so long as you are not setting the transition to effect changes in opacity.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/NysLM/)**

```
$('.div1').click(function () {
    if ($('.div2').is(':visible')) {
        $('.div2').fadeOut(3000);
        $('.div2').css('height', '0px');
    } else {
        $('.div2').fadeIn(3000);
        $('.div2').css('height', '400px');
    }
});

.div1 {
    height:20px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
}
.div2 {
    display:none;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    transition: background-color 3s, height 3s;
}
```

Here's why this works:

> The .fadeOut() method **animates the opacity** of the matched elements.
>   Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none,
>   so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

<sup>From the [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)</sup>

So, basically both fadeOut and fadeIn animate the opacity of the element, if you set `transition: all` or `transition: opacity` you're trying to run two different animations on the same property at the same time.

To work around this you can simply specify which properties you want the css transition to apply to.

Rather than using this:

```
.some_element {
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Use this:

```
.some_element {
    transition: height 1s, background-color 1s, some_other_property 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery .fadeOut()/.fadeIn() will not work with Transition. Because CSS Transition equivalent to them. As they are equivalent, always the last option will be in action. If you want both try CSS animation property. This could help you-
http://jsfiddle.net/webdevron/9a79L/

Again if you want to use a jQuery function then write as bellow:

```
cloned.css('transition', 'none');
    cloned.fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
```

Comment: Don't remove the link that you added before ! It may helpful to Others also..@webdevron

Comment: I thought that was not relevant. Okay, here it is-
http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/animation-css-transitions-jquery-easy/